# Android listview items

Tags: java, android, listview

I have the ListView and it contains some items (usually 7-10 ones). Every item contains the checkbox. I want to iterate all items in this listview and check all checkboxes in them. I try to do it so:

```
     ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myList);
     int count = list.getCount();

     for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
         View view = ((CheckBox)list.getChildAt(i);     
         view.findViewById(R.id.myCheckbox)).setChecked(true);
     }
```

But when i == 4 i have NullPointerException. I suppose when i use getChildAt method i can get only items displayed on the screen and returns null for items that do not fit on the screen. Can i get all items from ListView  and not just those on the screen?

Comment: Your item in adapter should contain state about being checked/unchecked and set it when user click on it.